# Provision EC2 Instance in an abitrary availability zone via cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, amazon-vpc

My AWS solution spans over 3 availability zones. In my backend the user is able to trigger a heavy compute job with beefy px instances. Therefore I wrote a CFN template, which provision all resorucess to execute the compute job (secret store, IAM Role, EC2 instance, log group). However when I try to create the template, it returns with a 500 and states that no capacity for my instance type is available for the availability zone i choose. My template provides a subnet for the EC2 instance and an availability zone for the attached volume. In the end I don't care in which availability zone the ec2 is provisioned as long it is in one of my subnets. Does someone know a way to provision an EC2 instance and it's volume (with cloudforamtion) by not specifically choosing one availability zone, but rather provide a range of subnets/availability zones ?

TLDR:
Does someone know a way to provision an EC2 instance and it's volume (with cloudforamtion) by not specifically choosing one availability zone, but rather provide a range of subnets/availability zones ?

Comment: CloudFormation doesn't really work like that. It doesn't try to launch a resource in one zone and, if it fails, try to launch it in a different zone. Also, the AWS::EC2::Instance specifically does not support a list of subnet IDs. One option you might look into is an autoscaling group with min=1, max=1 because ASG supports a list of subnet IDs. Haven't tested this.

Comment: Another option could be a custom resource. You could write a Lambda function that receives parameters from the CloudFormation template, largely as you have now with EC2 instance plus additional subnet IDs, and tries to launch an instance in each subnet in turn.

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look into autoscaling. I also thought about lambda, but the timeout of 15 minutes might be to slow, when the function needs to wait for the responses

Comment: How long do you typically find p2/p3/p4 instances take to start?

Comment: When I start the template via taskcat, it usually takes 10 minutes before it times out